# How to use a textfield and dynamic foreach using SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to develop a function like HTML select box having a searching in SwiftUI.

Now I wrote the code like below.

[image]

```
let fruits : [String] = ["Apple", "Banana", "StrawBerry", "Grape", "Watermelon"]
    @State var searchText = ""
    var filterdFruits: [String] {
        fruits.filter {
            searchText.isEmpty ? true : $0.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
        }
}


VStack {
      TextField("Search ...", text: $searchText,onEditingChanged: { Bool in
           if Bool{
                 show = true
              }else{
                 show = false
              }
            }).onChange(of: searchText) {newValue in
                  show = true
           }
                    

       if show{
           ForEach(filterdFruits, id: \.self) { fruit in
              Text(fruit)
                .onTapGesture {
                   searchText =  fruit
                   show = false
                 }  
           }
       }
}
```

This function purpose is `searchText` should have a value.
And some candidate should appear according to a value.

But I have a problem.

[image]

When I choice a item in Foreach, a searchText value is updated and it automatically has the value.

But `show` variable is not false.
Because `onChange` method is called.
If I delete `onChange` method, after I chose something in candidates I delete some word in textfield and there is no more candidates. It should be there.

[image]

My goal is if a user tap a candidate, candidate view will disappear and then searchText will have the same value.
If searchText is deleting, some candidate should be here.

How to resolve the problem?

Comment: Remove `onChange` on the search `TextField`, it will always reset `show` to true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem in your code lies in "onTapGesture" and "onchange" method. The code "onTapGesture" is executed before the code of "onchange" which cause the problem. However, the right execution of the code should be opposite.  Therefore, we need to add bit delay in "onTapGesture" code like done in below code to let "onchange" code execute first. In this way we can resolve your issue.

```
struct Test: View {
    let fruits: [String] = ["Apple", "Banana", "StrawBerry", "Grape", "Watermelon"]
    @State var searchText = ""
    @State var show = false
    
    var filterdFruits: [String] {
        fruits.filter {
            searchText.isEmpty ? true : $0.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Search ...", text: $searchText, onEditingChanged: { editing in
                show = editing
            })
            .onChange(of: searchText) { _ in
                show = true
            }
            if show {
                ForEach(filterdFruits, id: \.self) { fruit in
                    Text(fruit)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            searchText = fruit
                            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
                                show = false
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you feel difficulty in understanding the code. do let me know. I would appreciate. Thanks